# Reading a file in java using buffered reader correctly

Tags: java, java-8

I have the following code to read a file in java, and prints out the lines. I implemented it in two ways:

using streams:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
try (BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(file.toPath())) {
    list = br.lines().collect(Collectors.toList());
    Map<String, Long> totalCount = list.stream() .....
```

Using loops:

```
  try (FileReader reader = new FileReader(file);
             final BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(reader)) {
            String line;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {.. }
```

I was told this is the wrong, and using buffered reader is using features of the language wrongly. Is there a better way to this, i want to the know the correct way to use the language features.

Comment: I have always done it the second way shown, because I have been using Java since 1.3. I can see how someone who has only recently learned java would think the first way is the correct way. The only difference is that I write `try(BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file)))` because a close on the BufferedReader will close the reader (FileReader in this case) it is using, so no need to separate it. In your particular case, it looks like you want to collect lines into a map with a count, so saving the lines to a list first as in the first example is not as efficient.

Comment: Who said it was wrong, and what army?

Comment: "I was told this is the wrong": ask whoever told you that for clarification. Both styles are feasible for different situations (the first one loads the whole file into memory which can be an issue if you are loading a huge file, but is no problem for smaller files).

Comment: Instead of `br.lines().collect(Collectors.toList());` and then `list.stream()`, just use `br.lines()` directly in the first place (instead of `list.stream()`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two examples do two slightly different things. The key difference is that the first solution first reads all lines into memory, before then iterating the lines.

The second example reads the file line by line, this means that its content can be processed **line by line**.

First way: easy to write, read, and understand. But: as said, it reads the whole file into memory. Which isn't a problem for small files, but for really large files, this can create all kinds of issues (it takes time to read a large file, and you might run out of memory for really large files).

The other differences between the two approaches are somehow more "style", where: `br.lines()` already gives you a `Stream`, it doesn't make any sense to first collect the lines into a List object, to then stream that one.

Comment: But in the end, the preferable option is the third variant: `try(Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(file.toPath())) { /* use stream */}`

Comment: `var stream = ... ` ;-)

Comment: If the question wasn’t tagged with `java-8`…

Comment: Always remember that anonymous future reader who comes here and enjoys the java > 8 thoughts, too